# A Primitive element in Finite Fields

Tags: finite-fields, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

My question is about the roots of unity in finite fields. It goes like this:

Suppose we have two primes p and q, both greater than 3, which satisfy $q|(p-1)$. Then there exists a $q$-the root of unity (say $x, x \neq 1)$ in the field F with p elements. Suppose y is the inverse of 3 in F and consider the group $\displaystyle G = F^{*} \times F^{*} \times \ldots \times F^{*},$ a direct product of $\displaystyle \frac{q-1}{2}$ copies of the cyclic group $\displaystyle F^{*}.$ Clearly, $G$ is a group of exponent $p-1.$ Then can we say that the order of the element $ z = (y(1+x+x^{-1}), y(1+x^2+x^{-2}), \ldots, y(1+x^{\frac{q-1}{2}}+x^{- \frac{q-1}{2}}))$ is always of order $(p-1)$ in $G?$

Comment: Say, $x=1$. Then $y(1+x+x^{-1})=1$. But it is not a primitive element of $\Bbb F_p$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think it is reasonable to expect "$q$-th root of unity" meant "nontrivial $q$-th root of unity".  The fact that even under that assumption the result is false for $q = 5$ and the first two prime $p$ where $p \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ is more problematic. It has me wondering what numerical data led to the question.

Comment: I think we need more context. It often happens that then typos or misunderstandings can be corrected.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry for not mentioning that ≠1. Please find the updated version of my query. I checked it for few examples.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But the order of z can be something that is a proper divisor of (p-1). I am trying to claim that it is not the case here.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen my earlier comment was in response to a previous version of the question, where $G$ was just $F^\times$ rather than a product of copies of it. I am going to delete that earlier comment since now it is no longer relevant.

Comment: Ok.  Somehow I missed the edit. Sorry about creating confusion @KCd.